# Keep failing minting NFT with Candy Machine V2

Tags: metaplex, python

We use Python to mint NFTs. python solana.

Our last minting was in January 2023, but when we tried to mint again now, we confirmed in solscan that mpl was failing.
`Program returned error: custom program error: 0x4b`

According to the metaplex tweet, some modules of candy machine v2 were deprecated around March 2023. Could this be the cause?
So, I minted with python solana 0.20.0. and use solana-cli version 1.14.28.
Do I need to update to the most recent version?

Is there no way to successfully mint in mpl with python solana version 0.20.0?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you link us to what you mean with „python solana“? In general Candy Machine v2 is still working fine

Comment: I used this module from git.

https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py

If you do "pip install solana", the latest version is 0.32.0, but we were using 0.20.0 just fine.
Are you saying that Candy Machine v2 is working properly?
On their Twitter, they say that these are deprecated, so I'm guessing that the candy machine is the reason minting doesn't work.

https://twitter.com/metaplexstatus/status/1631464812361424897?s=46&t=m46WP-lQMQqfSK52SeWe2A

Comment: Can you please share your code and package version that you are using?

Comment: Yes, CM v2 works fine. The instructions this tweet references are not the ones cm v2 uses

Comment: As I said, I am using solana-py ver 0.20.0.
in my code, it returns true and success when minting has done. 
but solscan says my tx is failed.
If CM v2 is working fine, i have to upgrade my solana-py?